# How to return the row and column from a table in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I create another function `find_letter` that will return the row and column of a specific letter? I tried using `if(letter in table):` but it uses the original table. And if I write `if(letter in create_table()):` it tells me that the functions are not iterable. I also have no idea how to return the row and column of a given letter.

I gave up on creating a new function to find the row and column so I tried including a code with the `create_table` function but I am not sure about it.

Comment: It looks like `create_table` should either modify `table` or return something; currently it does neither. Also, why are you importing numpy and not using it?

Comment: I was stuck and tried literally everything I can. The create_table() makes the table into the alphabet table i showed, I didn't indent well in the question. I fixed it.

Comment: *“not neccesarily the order”* – If the order does not matter, and the size of that original table is hard coded, then why don’t you just create that table statically without having any logic that replaces stuff?

Comment: No the order matters but I just wanted to show an example, and the example isnt in the necessary order

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find where in your table desired character is, you can just do this. Result is a tuple containing row and column number.

```
def find_character(target_table, character):
    for row in range(len(target_table)):
        for column in range(len(target_table[row])):
            if target_table[row][column] == character:
                return row,column
```

Comment: How do I use the table from create_table(secret) ? If I define a new funtion find_character and call table, it will use the original one.

Comment: Updated it. You can just pass your table as an argument to this method.

Comment: It brings an error that says object of noneType has no len()

Comment: How are you calling this method?

Comment: table_r = create_table(secret)
//
def find_character(table_r, character):

Comment: You first write your function and then you call it using table_r as an argument. Do it like this: table_r = create_table(secret) //  print(find_character(table_r, character))

Comment: You have no return statement in your create_table method, which means you are passing "nothing" as an argument.

Comment: You might find [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) useful.

Comment: I see! thank you, i added a return statement from the print_table(table) as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

the following is a brutal solution (it assumes the character is in the table).

It returns a tuple containing row and column number.

```
def find_character(character, table):
    flat_table = [el for row in table for el in row]
    i = flat_table.index(character)
    return i / 5, i % 5

row, col = find_character(letter, table)
```

In case the table is ordered it can be simplified to

```
def find_character(character):
    i = ord(character) - ord('A') # use 65 if you prefer
    return i / 5, i % 5

row, col = find_character(letter)
```

By the way, a quick way to build such ordered table can be

```
from string import ascii_uppercase

itr = [iter(ascii_uppercase[:-1])] * 5
table = [list(z) for z in zip(*itr)]
```

Comment: Note the OP specifically says the table isn't necessarily in that order.